# Writing dBase III+ DBF and FPT with C#

Tags: c#, dbase

to support a rather old application I would like to write a dBase III+-File with C# that can be used in the legacy application directly.

To do so I have to create files containing a 0xF5 in the first byte, meaning it got a binary "111"/decimal "7" in the first three bits indicating the table version. I haven't found any specification describing what a 7 would be, but I guess it must be the indicator for dBase III+. 
Most notably the files can be opened with Excel directly without any error messages, a behavior I use as a test for the created files.

It seems though I don't configure my DB-connection correctly. I found two ways, that both worked partly:

1. An OleDbConnection by VFPOLEDB.1 / FoxPro. This creates DBF/**FPT**-files but in the first Byte it says 30, meaning a mere "1" in the first three version indicating bits. I also haven’t found a documentation telling me what a 1 means, but I guess it means "beyond ancient".
   The file won't open correctly in Excel and the legacy application can read and write but not append to the created table.
2. An OleDbConnection by Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 with Extended Properties=dBase III. This creates a DBF which can be opened in Excel, but as soon as I add a Memo-field a **DBT**-file ist created. The first Byte is 83, therefore the first three bits 100 (bin) or 4 (dec) meaning "dBase Level 7"

Can somebody tell me what driver to use for dBase III+ resp. DBF/**FPT**-files with version 111 (bin)/7 (dec)?

regards

Jens

Comment: Here is a description of the dBase file structure. It shows what the values of the first byte indicate. When referring to the bits in a byte, it is usual to start numbering from the right - so 0xF5 has 111 as the last three bits (101 as the first three). http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000325.shtml

Answer (score 0):

What we did was: The developer of the legacy software gave as an empty DBF and corresponding FPT of the table we wanted to write. Then we connected to this empty file via Visual FoxPro and inserted the data, leaving the handling of the long texts to the driver.